# Suppress Assert output in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible script that checks Linux file systems for capacity and issues a message if it is over a certain threshold.

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
     - name: Collect only facts about hardware
       setup:
         gather_subset:
           - 'hardware'

     - name: Test for available disk space
       setup: filter=ansible_mounts
       
     - name: Ensure that free space on the tested volume is greater than 15%
       assert:
         that:
           - mount.size_available > mount.size_total|float * 0.05
         fail_msg: Disk space on {{ item.mount }} has reached 95% threshold. Total size is {{ mount.size_total }} bytes and the available size is {{ mount.size_available }} 
         quiet: yes
       vars:
         mount: "{{ ansible_mounts | selectattr('mount','equalto',item.mount) | list | first }}"
       with_items:
         - "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
```

The problem is that even though I added `quiet: yes` I still get this as output on drives that are OK:

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed",
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "item": {
        "mount": "/boot",
        "device": "/dev/sda2",
        "fstype": "ext4",
        "options": "rw,nodev,relatime,data=ordered",
        "size_total": 1023303680,
        "size_available": 729440256,
        "block_size": 4096,
        "block_total": 249830,
        "block_available": 178086,
        "block_used": 71744,
        "inode_total": 65536,
        "inode_available": 65223,
        "inode_used": 313,
        "uuid": "75c887d9-e8a9-45a6-9bb8-8e7ffe4b9e68"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "_ansible_item_label": {
        "mount": "/boot",
        "device": "/dev/sda2",
        "fstype": "ext4",
        "options": "rw,nodev,relatime,data=ordered",
        "size_total": 1023303680,
        "size_available": 729440256,
        "block_size": 4096,
        "block_total": 249830,
        "block_available": 178086,
        "block_used": 71744,
        "inode_total": 65536,
        "inode_available": 65223,
        "inode_used": 313,
        "uuid": "75c887d9-e8a9-45a6-9bb8-8e7ffe4b9e68"
    }
}
```

And this on the failed:

```
{
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "assertion": "mount.size_available > mount.size_total|float * 0.05",
    "msg": "Disk space on /snap/core/8268 has reached 95% threshold. Size 0 Total size 93454336",
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "mount": "/snap/core/8268",
        "device": "/dev/loop0",
        "fstype": "squashfs",
        "options": "ro,nodev,relatime",
        "size_total": 93454336,
        "size_available": 0,
        "block_size": 131072,
        "block_total": 713,
        "block_available": 0,
        "block_used": 713,
        "inode_total": 12842,
        "inode_available": 0,
        "inode_used": 12842,
        "uuid": "N/A"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "_ansible_item_label": {
        "mount": "/snap/core/8268",
        "device": "/dev/loop0",
        "fstype": "squashfs",
        "options": "ro,nodev,relatime",
        "size_total": 93454336,
        "size_available": 0,
        "block_size": 131072,
        "block_total": 713,
        "block_available": 0,
        "block_used": 713,
        "inode_total": 12842,
        "inode_available": 0,
        "inode_used": 12842,
        "uuid": "N/A"
    }
}
```

I would like to suppress everything but the assert failed message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is to set an explicit `label` in a `loop_control` directive, which will suppress the default behavior of outputting the entire loop variable for each loop iteration.

But you're also doing something odd in the `vars` section of your task.

If we fix both of those, we get:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Collect only facts about hardware
      setup:
        gather_subset:
          - hardware

    - name: Test for available disk space
      setup:
        filter: ansible_mounts

    - name: Ensure that free space on the tested volume is greater than 15%
      assert:
        that:
          - item.size_available|float > item.size_total|float * 0.05
        fail_msg: Disk space on {{ item.mount }} has reached 95% threshold. Total size is {{ item.size_total }} bytes and the available size is {{ item.size_available }} 
        quiet: yes
      loop: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.mount }}"
```

Which will output something like this for healthy filesystems:

```
ok: [host0] => (item=/)
```

And something like this for filesystems that fail your assert:

```
failed: [host1] (item=/vol/failed) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "assertion": "item.size_available|float > item.size_total|float * 0.05", "changed": false, "evaluated_to": false, "item": {"block_available": 0, "block_size": 131072, "block_total": 444, "block_used": 444, "device": "/dev/loop4", "fstype": "squashfs", "inode_available": 0, "inode_total": 10809, "inode_used": 10809, "mount": "/vol/failed", "options": "ro,nodev,relatime", "size_available": 0, "size_total": 58195968, "uuid": "N/A"}, "msg": "Disk space on /vol/failed has reached 95% threshold. Total size is 58195968 bytes and the available size is 0"}
```

Note that the contents of `ansible_mounts` may contain filesystems that legitimately have no free space (e.g., read-only squashfs or isofs mounts), or that don't have `size_total` and `size_available` keys. You might want to add  a filter onto your task, for example:

```
    - name: Ensure that free space on the tested volume is greater than 15%
      assert:
        that:
          - item.size_available|float > item.size_total|float * 0.05
        fail_msg: Disk space on {{ item.mount }} has reached 95% threshold. Total size is {{ item.size_total }} bytes and the available size is {{ item.size_available }} 
        quiet: yes
      when: >
        "size_total" in item and item.fstype in ['xfs', 'ext4']
      loop: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.mount }}"
```

With that filter in place, the output on my system is:

```
TASK [Ensure that free space on the tested volume is greater than 15%] **************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/var/lib/snapd/snap/mame/2287)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/boot)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1514)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/home)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/var/lib/snapd/snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/10707)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/1944)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/var/lib/snapd/snap/mame/2235)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/lib/libvirt)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/lib/containers)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/lib/packages)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/lib/mock)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/vol/log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/scratch)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/cache)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked flawlessly. I love the filter idea.